# Region Growing needs to get compared

Tags: image-segmentation

I am currently doing a project in Matlab regarding liver segmentation. I used region growing for that. I need to compare the region growing method with any other method. Can you suggest me any segmentation method?(It must be worser than region growing. Because I need to prove mine is best.)Kindly help me out.

Comment: Just curious are you making a research paper?

Comment: Just final year project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to show a really bad method, try e.g. Otsu segmentation (`graythresh` in Matlab), which will fail on most complex images.

However, setting out to find a really bad method to show that yours is good is intellectually dishonest. Instead, you should test your method against a either some state of the art algorithm (would clustering of greyvalues be useful in your case?), or to manual segmentation, where you have somebody draw an outline onto the image.

It is possible that the other method is better. However, when you compare to manual segmentation, your method is most likely faster, and then you can discuss whether the trade-off between speed and quality is acceptable.

Comment: Thank you so much. I need some help regarding assessing the segmentation. Can you kindly guide me?

Comment: @Gomathi: That's quite a challenging question. I suggest you ask it on dsp.stackexchange.com.